# yield with region in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In my meteor.js application, some pages have side menu, some pages do not have. This is my layout.html

```
<template name="layout">
<div class="container">
    {{> header}}
   <div id="main" class="col-md-3">
        {{> yield region="sidenavigation"}}
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="col-md-9">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Let's say I have x template which has side menu, and y template which does not have side menu. When I render x template, everything is good. But when I render y template, because it does not have side menu, the content is pushed to the right expectedly. How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use {{#contentFor region=''}} in the template or page that you want to show the side menu in

eg.

```
<template name="yourtemplatename">
  {{#contentFor region="sidenavigation"}}
    ..
    ...
    ....
  {{/contentFor}}

</template>
```

example https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-building-an-application-with-meteor-and-iron-router